# How to setup zeppelin in order to import python file into zeppelin as a package?

Tags: python, apache-zeppelin

Background:
There is an existing python file which define a class and some methods. Now there is a need to call the class's method in Zeppelin.

Question:
How to setup zeppelin in order to import python file into zeppelin as a package?

Exception:
from myclass import myfunction

myfunction(x,y)